# How to use the Modx Revolution API

Tags: php, modx, modx-revolution

I have a client who is looking at having some other company develop an iPad application that will pull resources out of their existing modx instance. [no - I don't know why it needs to be an app.... ]

They are looking to use the Modx API, which from what I can tell so far needs to have a connector or something written as it does not "just work" correct?

So basically I need to write a connector that will handle the authentication [API key type idea] and pass all the data back and forth? Looking here: http://rtfm.modx.com/display/revolution20/Loading+MODx+Externally I see two methods of connecting/using modx - what is the advantage of "loading modx externally" over "Loading modx in api mode"

I found the API documentation easily enough but pretty much ZERO on actually using it.

So:

1. are there API usage docs anywhere?
2. what is the advantages/pro/cons of the load external vs. load as API methods
3. are all my assumptions above correct, or did I miss something really basic?

Answer (score 2):

Documentation that you have found enough to use API modx. Once you connect mode API ( http://rtfm.modx.com/display/revolution20/Loading+MODx+Externally - The third example I like best ) You can use modx processors to do whatever is necessary, as example authenticate the user:

```
if(isset($_POST) && count($_POST)){
    $c = array(
        'username' => $_POST['username'],
        'password' => $_POST['password']
    );
    $response = $modx->runProcessor('security/login',$c);
    if($response->response['success'] == 1){
        $user['id'] = $modx->user->get('id');
                $profile = $modx->user->getOne('Profile');
        $user['fullname'] = $profile->get('fullname');
        $user['email'] = $profile->get('email');
        echo json_encode($user);
    }else{
        echo json_encode($response->response); 
    }
}
```

simple getting resources:

```
if ($res = $modx->getObject('modResource', 1)) {
    print_r($res->toArray());
}
```

or advanced getting:

```
$response = $modx->runProcessor('resource/get', array('id' => 1));
if (!$response->isError()) {
    print_r($response->response['object']);
}
else {
    $modx->log(modX::LOG_LEVEL_ERROR, $response->getMessage());
}
```

Answer (score 0):

ModX documentation hasn't been its forte over the years, but here are few links.

First, understand how [ModX works and was architected](http://rtfm.modx.com/revolution/2.x/developing-in-modx) so you can develop with/for it.

ModX's API reference is at https://api.modx.com/revolution/2.2/. There you will find all the methods available, its properties and parameters. It's not a guide but a reference so don't expect too much literature.

Since version 2.3 you can build your [own API on top of ModX](http://rtfm.modx.com/revolution/2.x/developing-in-modx/advanced-development/developing-rest-servers). Very useful for customizing RESTful endpoints but unless you have some experience working/building API's this might be challenging.

Finally, if you're looking for a more in-depth documentation [check out the books](http://modx.com/learn/modx-books/other-modx-books/).

For example this is how you'd make the ModX object available from outside:

```
<?php
require_once '/absolute/path/to/modx/config.core.php';
require_once MODX_CORE_PATH.'model/modx/modx.class.php';
$modx = new modX();
$modx->initialize('web');
$modx->getService('error', 'error.modError');
```